# creating an If statement to remove elements from an array

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I have a numpy array called stack, let's say 50 by 50, which has a specific value at each position (for example `stack[23, 19] = -0.13`).
I am trying to create an if statement where if the value at any position, is below a certain value, that value is turned into 0.
so if `stack[23, 19] = -0.13` before the if statement, it would turn into `stack[23, 19] = 0` after the statement. 
So far I have

```
peaks = stack
if abs(peaks[i, i]) > -1.2 or abs(peaks[i, i]) < 1.2:
    peaks[i, i] = 0
```

And I wants 'peaks' to retain the same 50 by 50 shape of 'stack', 
but this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: `abs(peaks[i, i]) > -1.2` not sure what abs does, but if that's the absolute function of python, it will always return true

Comment: abs(x) will always greater than or equal to zero, however even after changing it you don't get desired solution then please show a way how you are initializing array(or sample of array) and loop to iterate all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to map a function over your numpy array. A good way to do so is to use `numpy.vectorize`:

```
def my_condition(x) :
     if abs(x)<1.2 : 
     #know that abs refers to the absolute value
          return 0
     return x
vfunct=np.vectorize(my_condition)
peaks=vfunct(stack)
```